# Ordenar divs pela data no formato dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, classificação, order

Alguém sabe como posso ordenar um conjunto de divs através de uma data presente em seu conteúdo?

por exemplo:

```
<div class="box" id="box1">
    <div class="date">01/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box2">
    <div class="date">04/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box3">
    <div class="date">08/05/2018</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".box").each(function(){

        var date_content = $(this).find(".date").html();

        //aqui seria o momento de adicionar um codigo para ordena-los.. 
        //preciso que apareça da data maior até a menor.. ou seja, o primeiro box com a data mais recente, e os seguintes com as datas mais antigas... 

    });//end each

});//end doc
</script>
```

Comment: mas já estão ordenadas

Comment: _preciso que apareça da data maior até a menor.. ou seja, o primeiro box com a data mais recente, e os seguintes com as datas mais antigas..._

Comment: A ordenação que me refiro é com relação a data que contém no html, por exemplo, para ficar como eu gostaria, iniciando com a data mais recente e seguindo até a mais antiga, ficaria #box3, #box2, #box1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `.sort()` fazendo comparação direta de datas, basta converter o formato `dd/MM/yyyy` para `yyyy/MM/dd`. Inclusive irá manter as respectivas `id`s de cada `div` intactas, porque irá apenas muda-las de posição:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var divs = $('.box').get(); // array com as divs
   
   divs.sort(function(a, b){
      
      var da = $('.date', a).text().split("/"); // converto p/ array o 'a'
      var db = $('.date', b).text().split("/"); // converto p/ array o 'b'
      
      da = new Date(da[2], da[1]-1, da[0]).getTime(); // converto em Date
      db = new Date(db[2], db[1]-1, db[0]).getTime(); // converto em Date
      
      return db - da; // comparo as datas (maior primeiro)
   });

   $.each(divs, function(idx, divs){
      $('body').append(divs); // reinsiro as divs ordenadas no body
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box1">
    <div class="date">01/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box2">
    <div class="date">04/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box5">
    <div class="date">01/07/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box3">
    <div class="date">08/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box6">
    <div class="date">01/01/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box4">
    <div class="date">18/04/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box5">
    <div class="date">02/02/2019</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi dvd, testei agora, com seu formato teve uma boa adaptação, consegui implementar. Obrigado a vc e a todos que contribuiram!

Comment: Oi, acabei reabrindo, pq em alguns casos não funcionou... ou não compreendi mto bem. Não identifiquei em qual momento em q interpretamos a classe 'date' do html para compara-la.. quando mudei algumas datas não reorganizou os boxes

Comment: Funciona de primeira.. mas depois começa a não atualizar conforme vou trocando as datas

Comment: sim, cada box é um arquivo em uma pasta.. e fora dela tenho um arquivo que carrega todos, com php, um include com while, para que todos na pasta sejam carregados

Comment: nesse caso não, precisei fazer com php esse include com while, pq cada box, eh um arquivo. Então cada vez q um arquivo eh criado nessa pasta, esse box surge automatico

Comment: Não entendi direito. Vc tá adicionando elementos na página de forma dinâmica sem Ajax. Como assim? Está recarregando a página?

Comment: Sem ajax. Recarrego o nav

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda no chat, era apenas a forma de implementar na minha estrutura, resolvido com a sua function de ordenar()!

Comment: oi @dvd, estava dando continuidade a implementação do recurso, e senti a necessidade de ter a verificação pela hora, além da data.. vc sabe como ficaria nessa estrutura?

Comment: vou dar uma olhada...

Comment: Como seria exibida essa hora no HTML?

Comment: Ooi @dvd, no html ficaria em uma div, ao lado da data, por exemplo: <div class="status"><span class="date">25/04/2015</span> <span class="hour">00:08:33</span></div>

Comment: Pq a ideia eh q o mais recente sempre seja mostrado em primeiro lugar na ordem.. e sem a hora, está ocorrendo de não aparecer em alguns momentos..

Comment: Blz... eu vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76550/discussion-between-dvd-and-neo).

Comment: Coloquei a implementação de hora como vc disse @dvd, funcionou corretamente, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 4):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date-list">
  <div class="box" id="box1">
      <div class="date">01/05/2018</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="box2">
      <div class="date">30/05/2018</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="box3">
      <div class="date">08/05/2018</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box" id="box3">
      <div class="date">15/11/2001</div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="box" id="box3">
      <div class="date">08/05/1998</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dates = [] //Criando um array de datas
    $(".box").each(function(){
        dates.push($(this).find(".date").html());
    });
    
    // Convertendo dd/MM/yyyy para yyyyMMdd
    function dateToNum(d) {
      d = d.split("/");
      console.log(Number(d[2]+d[1]+d[0]));
      return Number(d[2]+d[1]+d[0]);
    }
    
    //Ordenando através da função sort(> para ordem decrescente, < para ordem crescente)
    dates.sort(function(a,b){
      return dateToNum(a) < dateToNum(b);
    });
    
    //Popula a div de datas através de um array passado
    function populateDataList(_dates){
      $("#date-list").html("");
      $.each(_dates, function(index,value){
      
        $("#date-list").append(
          ("<div class='box' id='box{id}'><div class='date'>{date}</div></div>").replace("{id}",index).replace("{date}",value)
        );
      });
    }
    populateDataList(dates);

});//end doc
</script>
```

Eu estou re-populando com o `id` da *box* em relação a posição da data dentro do `Array`, caso seja necessário ter o mesmo ID me avise que eu corrijo.

Qualquer duvida só comentar ^^

Comment: Leonardo, seu código não funciona corretamente. Se tu substituis `04/05/2018` por `10/05/2018`, ele não irá organizar.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr tem razão, eu ia remover mas vou descobrir porque isso acontece antes, caso não consiga eu removo.

Comment: O problema era o sinal de operação, o correto no meu caso é utilizar > <

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `sort` para comparar qual maior valor e organizá-los.

**Segue exemplo comentado:**

```js
/* Captura todos os elementos data */
let $datesElement = document.querySelectorAll(".date")

/* Organiza do maior para o menor */
$dates = [...$datesElement].sort( (a, b) => {

  /**
   * Separa os valores através da barra. O JavaScript pois
   * não suporta operações com a data no formato dd/mm/aaaa
   */
  $dateA = a.firstChild.textContent.split("/")
  $dateB = b.firstChild.textContent.split("/")
  
  /* Cria os objetos data e captura o tempo em millisegundos para comparar qual maior */
  return new Date($dateA[2], $dateA[1], $dateA[0]).getTime() < new Date($dateB[2], $dateB[1], $dateB[0]).getTime()
});

/**
 * Percorre as datas já organizadas
 * remove o elemento .box e adiciona os 
 * organizados por data
 */
for (let $date of $dates) {
  $date.parentElement.remove();
  document.body.appendChild($date)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" id="box1">
    <div class="date">01/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box2">
    <div class="date">04/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box3">
    <div class="date">19/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box4">
    <div class="date">05/05/2018</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi valdeir, vou testar

Comment: Desculpe, talvez eu não tenha compreendido como implementar, mas não funcionou

Comment: @Neo Se possível, poste o código que você fez, no site https://hastebin.com/. Assim fica mais fácil analisar.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      function toDate(value)
      {
        var from = value.split("/");
        return (new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]));
        
      }
      var a = $('.box').sort(function (a, b) {
         //assumindo que o valor do atributo será sempre uma data válida
         var contentA = toDate($(a).attr('dueDate')).getTime();
         
         var contentB = toDate($(b).attr('dueDate')).getTime();
         
         return (contentB < contentA) ? -1 : (contentB > contentA) ? 1 : 0;
      });
    $('.box').parent().html(a);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>


<div class="box" id="box1" dueDate="01/05/2013">
    <div class="date">01/05/2013</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box2" dueDate="01/06/2013">
    <div class="date">01/06/2013</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box3" dueDate="04/05/2014">
    <div class="date">04/05/2014</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box4" dueDate="01/06/2015">
    <div class="date">01/06/2015</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box5" dueDate="08/05/2018">
    <div class="date">08/05/2018</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box6" dueDate="04/12/2020">
    <div class="date">04/12/2020</div>
</div>
```

> getTime() retorna o valor numérico correspondente ao horário da data especificada de acordo com o horário universal.
>
> **compare as datas em milissegundos**

Comment: desculpe, coloquei no JsFiddle para testar e não funcionou, o que pode ter acontecido? https://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/3922/

Comment: @Neo Funciona sim, veja https://jsfiddle.net/o5n3es6s/

Comment: Oi leo, obrigado pelo envio do link, visualizei funcionando. Implementei recentemente com o formato do @dvd. Agradeço a vc e a todos pela contribuição!

Comment: @Neo, só pra exclarecer, coloquei aqui no codigo dentro da função   `window.onload=function(){` porque na maioria das vezes o usuario não sabe onde colocar no codigo. Com essa função pode colocar onde quiser. Sem essa função só funciona depois do HTML. No `JsFiddle` não pode colocar ela!

Comment: ah perfeito, foi isso então

Comment: @Neo exato, considere como um bonus :) - mais um aprendizado

Comment: estava testando no fiddle.. percebi que apenas interpreta o dia, mas se o mês e o ano forem modificados, continua a oredenação antiga...

Comment: **Sugestão:** troque `window.onload` por `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` ou por `$(function () { ... })` (que são equivalentes), `$.ready` é bem mais "rápido" que onload, pois não precisa esperar os resources como imagens ou estilos carregadores.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, ok, já troquei, thanks, mas me explica porque pra poder aprimorar meus conhecimentos!

Comment: @Neo não sei como vc viu isso não, acho que vc marcou bobeira. Acontece, eu tb marquei bobeira nos ids, já editei a pergunta

Comment: o `window.onload` primeiramente não é um evento listner, ou seja pode ser sobreescrito por outras libs ou afins, no caso se precisar mesmo de onload prefira usar assim `$(window).load(function () {});` no jQuery.... Agora a diferença entre onload e ready é simples, onload precisa esperar até que todos resources tenham sido carregados, como imagens, outros scripts e etc, já o `jQuery.ready` ($.ready, `$(document).ready(function() {})` e `$(function() {})`) esperam apenas que a estrutura do documento HTML tenha sido carregada, ou seja não precisa esperar outros resources ...

Comment: ... então se a pagina tiver muitas imagens com onload pode demorar do seu "sort" ocorrer. Já com ready precisa somente que o HTML tenha sido baixado e renderizado para que o jQuery possa interagir com o DOM.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tu é bruxo, rsrs!! Valeu!!

Comment: @Leo, então era a questão dos ids? certinho então